Why is this a circular reference in Swift 5.10?
Why does extension A: A.Nested.Doable (last line) cause a circular reference in the following Swift 5.10 code?
class Parent1 {
    
}

class Parent2 {
    
}

class A: Parent1 {

}

extension A { class Nested: Parent2 {
    
} }

extension A.Nested { protocol Doable {
    
} }

extension A: A.Nested.Doable {
    
}

If don't make A.Nested inherit from anything, then no circular reference is found in the code by Xcode.
Xcode 15.3, MacBook Air M1 8GB, macOS Sonoma 14.4.1.

Why create code like this, what is the purpose of having nested classes and protocol definitions like this? You are saying that A conforms to Doable but the protocol is an internal type inside A, I can't get my head around how that should work.

@JoakimDanielson In my specific case I have a view controller subclass that defines a table view cell subclass and I wanted to use the delegate pattern to make the view controller communicate with the cell, particularly I wanted to inject the view controller into the cell as a certain protocol (interface segregation), to which the view controller would have to conform, and nesting definitions helps me reduce (re)naming burden.

As I see it, if you define a protocol you should do it in the same or outside the scope as the type(s) that should conform to it.

If it helps, it compiles when you put class A together without adding the protocol conformance via extension:
class A: Parent1, A.Nested.Doable {
    class Nested: Parent2 {
        protocol Doable {

        }
    }
}

